# Avoid repetition of rows in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, rows, repeat

I have a table with 14 columns and what i want to do is avoid the insertion of duplicate rows i.e i don't want to have two rows with same 14 values. With a combination of `SELECT`, `WHERE` and `AND` clause we can avoid insertion of duplicate rows for couple of columns but can i apply the same for 14 columns? It would be like having 13 `AND` to it and i'm not even sure whether it's gonna work or not. Is their any other way to do it? And my 14 columns can have repetitive values in it so making each and everyone `UNIQUE` is out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a unique index on the table:

```
create unique index t_allcols on t(col1, col2, . . . col14);
```

This will enforce that all combinations of fields are unique (when they have values).

EDIT:

You can create the index when you create the table.  Then the database will automatically do the check when you try to insert new data.  This is the safest way to validate the data.

If you want to do a check when you are inserting the data, then you can do something like:

```
insert into t(col1, . . ., col14)
    select val1, . . ., val14
    where not exists (select 1 from t where col1 = val1 and col2 = val2 and . . .);
```

Comment: @NottyShinchan . . . It works automatically.  That is what a unique index does (you can read about indexes here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html).

Comment: so if i have to write that in a script, i do it before insert or after insert. My main motive is to use it with script. It's written in python. can you tell me the limitation of `AND` clause. On how many columns can we use it?

Comment: I already tried that 14 column thing with multiple `AND` it's getting too lengthy and complicated too but it didn't seemed to work i don't know why. I'll give it a try again